# Dockerfile: ADD and COPY fails without error

Tags: dockerfile

When building the Dockerfile, no errors occur. This is true for `COPY` and `ADD`

```
Step 6/6 : COPY linter /etc/
 ---> 4cc83d919016
Successfully built 4cc83d919016
```

The image gets tagged and pushed as if everything worked correctly. When I attach to the container after pull and run, the directory `/etc/linters` is not present.

How to debug/resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking questions here is somehow catalytic...

The problem was, that my command just copied the **content of** `linter` to `/etc/`

What I wanted to achieve was, to add the complete dir to `/etc`. The correct add command would be:

```
ADD linter /etc/linter/
```